# Reading data from file and filling in STL vector

Tags: c++, stl

```
struct DataValue
{
    DataValue() : uiQuality(0) {} // Here 0 stands for good.
    unsigned int    uiQuality;
    std::string     timeChanged;
    float           value;
};

std::vector<DataValues> myDataValues
```

At some point in my application data in my vector is filled. I am writing to a file using below.

```
std::ofstream myfile("myData.txt", std::ios::app);

for (int j = 0; j < myDataValues.size(); j++)
{
    std::string quality;
    if(myDataValues[j].quality == 0) {
        quality = "good";
    }
    else {
        quality = "bad";
    }
    myfile << myDataValues[j].timeChanged.c_str() << "  " <<  myDataValues[j].value  << "  " <<  quality << std::endl; 
}
```

File looks like below.

```
2012-06-25 12:41:56.789  55  good
2012-06-25 12:51:14.782  55  good
2012-06-25 05:25:16.456  62.6925  good
2012-06-25 05:26:11.458  63.4109  good
2012-06-25 05:27:01.459  63.0383  good
2012-06-25 05:27:56.959  61.5266  good
2012-06-25 05:29:01.959  58.5354  good
2012-06-25 05:32:06.963  47.5656  good
2012-06-25 05:33:06.964  44.9916  good
2012-06-25 05:33:11.963  44.8267  good
2012-06-25 05:34:06.965  43.6011  good
2012-06-25 05:34:56.965  43.493  good
2012-06-25 12:51:14.782  52.418  good
2012-06-25 09:49:54.112  0  good
2012-06-25 11:50:30.781  0  good
```

Now I have to read above file in other application and fill another vector for example. Fill vector wheter it is duplicate or not this check is not required.

```
 std::vector<DataValues> anotherDataValues
```

Request sample code How do I read data from above file and fill above vector?

How do I do this effectively.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: There are duplicates, but the main idea is something like (off the top of my head): `std::vector<std::string> anotherDataValues (std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(fileObject, " "), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>());`

Comment: While filling vector I don't have to check for dupliate, simply read data from file and read to vector Can you please elobaorate?

Comment: I meant duplicates of the question; I've seen a few lately. The code roughly initializes a vector using the `ostream_iterator` as a beginning and ending position to effectively read the file into a vector of strings. In short, it's a one-liner that's not as easy to understand as a short loop that does the same thing.

Comment: `std::string` does not have a member function `Format()`.

Comment: How do I read above vector of strings and fill the vector of my data type "DataValues"? Can you pls show sample code?

Comment: @venkysmarty, My memory isn't that great. I looked and there are two changes: 1. It should be `istream_iterator` (duh!), and 2. The first should just be `fileObject`, not `fileObject, " "`. I was mixing that up with the output I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious approach would be to write a `>>` (and `<<`) operators for
the class.  The insertion operator is pretty straightforward:

```
std::ostream&
operator<<( std::ostream& dest, DataValue const& data )
{
    dest << data.timeChanged << "  "
         << data.value << "  "
         << (data.uiQuality == 0 ? "good" : "bad");
    return dest;
}
```

Once you've done this, you can output the array by simply writing:

```
std::copy( myDataValues.begin(), myDataValues.end(),
           std::ostream_iterator<DataValue>( myFile, "\n" ) );
```

The `<<` operator is a bit trickier, because you have to deal with
possible errors in the format.  Given that the data format contains
spaces, I'd impose a `\n' as terminator, and do something like:

```
std::istream&
operator>>( std::istream& source, DataValue& dest )
{
    std::string line;
    if ( std::getline( source, line ) ) {
        std::istringstream parse( line );
        std::string date;
        std::string time;
        float value;
        std::string status;
        parse >> date >> time >> value >> status >> std::ws;
        if ( ! parse || (status != "good" && status != "bad") ) {
            source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
        } else {
            dest.timeChanged = date + ' ' + time;
            dest.value = value;
            dest.uiQuality = (status == "good" ? 0 : 1);
        }
    }
    return source;
}
```

Note that the whitespace in the date format complicates things.  If you
have some control over the format, I'd get rid of it.  (ISO uses a `'T'`
to separate date and time, for example.)  Regardless, using some
sort of a class for `DataTime` makes sense; this class would, of course,
provide its own `>>` and `<<`, which you could then use in the above.

Once you've done this, reading becomes trivial as well:

```
std::vector<DataValue> v(
    (std::istream_iterator<DataValue>( myFile )),
    (std::istream_iterator<DataValue>()) );
```

(Note the extra parentheses.  Necessary on at least one of the arguments
to avoid the most embaressing parse problem.)

Answer (score 1):

You should first figure out how you will read *one* DataValue object.  Then filling a vector of them is easy.  Here's how you might do it (though you should probably provide more comprehensive error checking).

```
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, DataValue & dv) {
    std::string date, time, quality;
    float value;
    if (is >> date >> time >> value >> quality) {
        if (quality == "good")
            dv.uiQuality = 0;
        else if (quality == "bad")
            dv.uiQuality = 1;
        else {
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            return is;
        }
        dv.timeChanged = date + " " + time;
        dv.value = value;
    }
    return is;
}
```

Then, you can fill the vector simply like this:

```
std::ifstream fin("myData.txt");
std::istream_iterator<DataValue> beg(fin), end;
std::vector<DataValue> v(beg,end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you could just `push_back` on the stl vector.  However, if you are doing that, and know about how long your vector is.  You could also use the `reserve` function to request enough space be stored so that the vector doesn't need to be resized.

Alternatively, you could also use the `resize` function call, and fill in the stl vector that is already of the size you need.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

You can also get the data from ifstream's `getline` function

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/

Comment: I should not push_back at same place. I am reading file in another application.